# How to solve the problem of vscode saving .vue files

Tags: visual-studio-code

When my vscode saves the .vue file, it will overwrite the script content as [object Promise].

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCr7E.png)

I tried reinstalling vscode to no avail.